# How to authenticate my signalR client with IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, signalr, identityserver4

In my client, I use this code to get a token, "http://localhost:5006" is my IdentityServer (the authority)

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var discoveryDocument = httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5006").Result;
var tokenResponse = httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
    new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
        ClientId = "client",
        ClientSecret = "Prevo100",
        Scope = "prevo100-api"
    }).Result;
```

My signalR hub is http://localhost:5119/Prevo100", I got this exception when I run StartAsync :

> System.AggregateException : 'One or more errors occurred. (Response
> status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).)'

I can also have 401 error !

```
var url = "http://localhost:5119/Prevo100";

HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(url, options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

var client = new Prevo100WebClient(connection);

connection.StartAsync().Wait(); // <== Exception here
```

In the SignalR server (hub), I use this code :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5006";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.Audience = "prevo100-api";

            options.TokenValidationParameters =
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };

            // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
            // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
            // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
            // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

            // Sending the access token in the query string is required when using WebSockets or ServerSentEvents
            // due to a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
            // SignalR hub in this code.
            // See https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
            // for more information about security considerations when using
            // the query string to transmit the access token.
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                    // If the request is for our hub...
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/Prevo100"))
                    {
                        // Read the token out of the query string
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        //hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval // 30 secondes par défaut
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<Prevo100Hub>("/Prevo100");
    });
}
```

I added an attribute the hub class :

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class Prevo100Hub : Hub<IPrevo100Client>, IHubContract
{
//....
}
```

Comment: I have a blog post about troubleshooting JwtBearer problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Could you create a test controller with the same attribute ? To check if it works, if not works, please set break in this line, and check it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). We need more details, if there is some sensitive info, you need to hide it.

Comment: @ToreNestenius the "accessToken" variable is empty in the server when I can connect with the signalR client

Comment: @JasonPan I replaced the IdentityServer authentication with the authentication used in the JwtSample and JwtClientSample examples https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/SignalR/samples and I still have an exception (401 - Unauthorized) when I try to start the hub connection

Comment: I got the 401 error when I slow debugged the modified program (to comply with the samples) otherwise it works.

Comment: @Aminos Seems there are some configurations issue in your project. Could you create a minimal sample which can reproduce the issue for me ? I am willing to check it, please hide the sensitive info, it could protect your data safely.

Comment: @JasonPan I made a repo here : https://github.com/embeddedmz/AspNetSignalRAuthenticationExamples first launch the signalR/identity server project then launch the client, you will have a 403 error.

Comment: Hi Aminos, I checked the repo and will post the answer below, you can follow my steps to check it.

Comment: I just help you find the auth issue, seems there are still have some error in your index.html, you can find it in console window when using the developer tools in browser.

Comment: @Tore Nestenius I'm getting 401 with this error message: "Www-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", but I can access others endpoints with [Authorize] attribute

Comment: I did blog about diagnosing token JwtBearer token issues here: https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

do also validate the token on https://jwt.io

can you post a sample token?

Answer (score 0):

From the repo, we can know you have a Broadcaster hub(url is `/broadcast`) in your JwtSample project.
And you also have a Broadcaster hub(url is `/Prevo100`).

All the client side should get token from the api (`/generatetoken`) in SignalRIdentityServerServer.

I don't know why the  SignalRIdentityServerClient can't works well when I set the startup like below.

[image]

*Test Result*

[image]

But SignalRIdentityServerClient works well when I set the startup like below.

[image]

*Test Result*

[image]

I usually like to move the method which can generate the token in the identity server application.

**Here is the sample code, I have change it and it works well.**

*SignalRIdentityServerServer - Startup.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace SignalRIdentityServerServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        //private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32));
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler JwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.Scopes)
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                });
            });
            // Add services to the container.
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                    var secretByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Authentication:SecretKey");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "SignalRTestServer",
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = "SignalRTests",
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretByte),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };

                    // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
                    // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
                    // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
                    // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

                    // Sending the access token in the query string is required when using WebSockets or ServerSentEvents
                    // due to a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
                    // SignalR hub in this code.
                    // See https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
                    // for more information about security considerations when using
                    // the query string to transmit the access token.
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            /*var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            // If the request is for our hub...
                            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                (context.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest ||
                                context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "text/event-stream")
                                //&& path.StartsWithSegments("/Prevo100")
                                )
                            {
                                // Read the token out of the query string
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;*/

                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            // If the request is for our hub...
                            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) /*&&
                                path.StartsWithSegments("/Prevo100")*/)
                            {
                                // Read the token out of the query string
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseFileServer();
            app.UseRouting();

            
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<Broadcaster>("/Prevo100");
                endpoints.MapGet("/generatetoken", context =>
                {
                    return context.Response.WriteAsync(GenerateToken(context));
                });
            });
        }

        private string GenerateToken(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var singningAlgorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256;

            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, httpContext.Request.Query["user"])
            };
            var secretByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Authentication:SecretKey");
            var signingkey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretByte);
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingkey, singningAlgorithm);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "SignalRTestServer",
                audience: "SignalRTests",
                claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3),
                signingCredentials
                );
            //var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, httpContext.Request.Query["user"]) };
            //var credentials = new SigningCredentials(SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            //var token = new JwtSecurityToken("SignalRTestServer", "SignalRTests", claims, expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30), signingCredentials: credentials);
            var tokenStr = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return tokenStr;
        }
    }
}
```

*JwtSample - Startup.cs*

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace JwtSample;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
            {
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5155";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.Audience = "prevo100-api";

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            //ValidateAudience = true,
            //ValidateIssuer = true
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = "SignalRTestServer",
            ValidAudience = "SignalRTests",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Authentication:SecretKey"))
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    (context.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest || context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "text/event-stream"))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseFileServer();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<Broadcaster>("/broadcast");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }


}
```

*JwtSample - index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SignalR JWT Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/signalr-client/signalr.js"></script>
<script>

    function createLog(clientId) {
        var log = document.getElementById('log');
        var ul =  document.createElement('ul');
        ul.id = 'log' + clientId;
        log.appendChild(ul);
    }

    function appendLog(clientId, entry) {
        var listId = document.getElementById('log' + clientId);
        if (listId.children.length > 11) {
            listId.removeChild(listId.children[1]);
        }
        var child = document.createElement('li');
        child.innerText = entry;
        listId.appendChild(child);
    }

    function get(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.send();
            xhr.onload = () => {
                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                    resolve(xhr.response || xhr.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    reject(new Error(xhr.statusText));
                }
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
                reject(new Error(xhr.statusText));
            }
        });
    }

    var tokens = {};

    function refreshToken(clientId) {

        console.log("clientId: " + clientId);
        //var tokenUrl = 'http://' + document.location.host + '/generatetoken?user=' + clientId;
        var tokenUrl = 'http://localhost:5155/generatetoken?user=' + clientId;
        return get(tokenUrl)
            .then(function (token) {
                tokens[clientId] = token;
            });
    }

    function runConnection(clientId, transportType) {
        var connection;
        console.log("clientId: " + clientId);
        refreshToken(clientId)
            .then(function () {
                var options = {
                    transport: transportType,
                    accessTokenFactory: function () { return tokens[clientId]; }
                };

                console.log(transportType)
                console.log("tokens: " + tokens[clientId]);
                connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl("/broadcast", { accessTokenFactory: () => tokens[clientId] })
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                    .build();

                connection.on('Message', function (from, message) {
                    appendLog(clientId, from + ': ' + message);
                });
                return connection.start();
            })
            .then(function () {
                appendLog(clientId, 'user ' + clientId + ' connected');
                setInterval(function () {
                    appendLog(clientId, 'Refreshing token');
                    refreshToken(clientId);
                }, 20000);
                setTimeout(function sendMessage() {
                    connection.send('broadcast', clientId, 'Hello at ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
                    var timeout = 2000 + Math.random() * 4000;
                    setTimeout(sendMessage, timeout);
                })
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                appendLog(clientId, 'Could not start connection');
            });
    }

    [signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets, signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents, signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling].forEach(function(transportType) {
        var clientId = 'browser ' + signalR.HttpTransportType[transportType];
        console.log("transportType: " + signalR.HttpTransportType[transportType]);
        createLog(clientId);
        appendLog(clientId, 'Log for user: ' + clientId);
        runConnection(clientId, transportType);
    });

</script>
```

*JwtClientSample - Program.cs*

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

namespace JwtClientSample;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new Program();
        await Task.WhenAll(
            app.RunConnection(HttpTransportType.WebSockets)/*,
            app.RunConnection(HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents),
            app.RunConnection(HttpTransportType.LongPolling)*/);
    }

    private const string ServerUrl = "http://localhost:54543";
    private const string ID4ServerUrl = "http://localhost:5155";

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> _tokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    private async Task RunConnection(HttpTransportType transportType)
    {
        var userId = "C#" + transportType;
        _tokens[userId] = GetJwtToken(userId);

        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(ServerUrl + "/broadcast", options =>
            {
                options.Transports = transportType;
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => _tokens[userId];
            })
            .Build();

        var closedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
        hubConnection.Closed += e =>
        {
            closedTcs.SetResult();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("Message", (sender, message) => Console.WriteLine($"[{userId}] {sender}: {message}"));
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"[{userId}] Connection Started");

        var ticks = 0;
        var nextMsgAt = 3;

        try
        {
            while (!closedTcs.Task.IsCompleted)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ticks++;
                if (ticks % 15 == 0)
                {
                    // no need to refresh the token for websockets
                    if (transportType != HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
                    {
                        _tokens[userId] = GetJwtToken(userId);
                        Console.WriteLine($"[{userId}] Token refreshed");
                    }
                }

                if (ticks % nextMsgAt == 0)
                {
                    await hubConnection.SendAsync("Broadcast", userId, $"Hello at {DateTime.Now}");
                    nextMsgAt = Random.Shared.Next(2, 5);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{userId}] Connection terminated with error: {ex}");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetJwtToken(string userId)
    {
        var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(ID4ServerUrl + $"/generatetoken?user={userId}");
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

*SignalRIdentityServerClient - Program.cs*

```
using IdentityModel.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using SignalRIdentityServerShared;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Data.Common;
using TypedSignalR.Client;

namespace SignalRIdentityServerClient
{
    public class WebClient : IClient, IHubConnectionObserver, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IHubContract _hub;
        private readonly IDisposable _subscription;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new();
        

        public WebClient(HubConnection connection)
        {
            _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy<IHubContract>(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            _subscription = connection.Register<IClient>(this);
        }

        Task IClient.ReceiveMessage(string sender, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", sender, message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task OnClosed(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[On Closed!]");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task OnReconnected(string connectionId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[On Reconnected!]");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task OnReconnecting(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[On Reconnecting!]");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task RequestBroadcast()
        {
            return _hub.Broadcast("Client", "Hello Server !");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _subscription?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> _tokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
        private const string ID4ServerUrl = "http://localhost:5155";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            //var discoveryDocument = httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5155").Result;
            //var tokenResponse = httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
            //    new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            //    {
            //        Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
            //        ClientId = "client",
            //        ClientSecret = "Prevo100",
            //        Scope = "prevo100-api"
            //    }).Result;

            //Console.WriteLine($"Token : {tokenResponse.AccessToken}");

            var userId = "C#" + HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            _tokens[userId] = GetJwtToken(userId);

            var url = "http://localhost:5155/Prevo100";

            HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(url, options =>
                {
                    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_tokens[userId].Result);
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

            var client = new WebClient(connection);

            connection.StartAsync().Wait();

            client.RequestBroadcast().Wait();

            //connection.StopAsync().Wait();
            client.Dispose();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetJwtToken(string userId)
        {
            var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(ID4ServerUrl + $"/generatetoken?user={userId}");
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I didn't read it all because the projects JwtClientSample and JwtSample must be ignored, I took a solution that contains these 2 projects that I took from ASP NET Core github repo to test another authentication method. The projects I'm interested in are those preceded by the SignalR prefix.

Comment: In fact, I want to use ClientSecret = "Prevo100" in SignalRIdentityServerClient - Program.cs (look at Config.cs, it contains identity server configuration) I don't want to use the JwtSample technique. again the projects JwtSample and JwtClientSample don't interest me.

Comment: Hi @Aminos Ok，let me point the important things, your client app and the identity sever app should have the same security key, can’t generate it by random fuction. If you can check the sample code I provided, you will learn a lot.

Comment: Hi Jason, isn't it Identity Server's job to do that ? As you can see, in SignalRIndetityServerClient, I request a token from IdentityServer, which I receive, and I want my client to be able to connect to the hub without the hub returning a 401 or 403 error. This technique works with classic web APIs (without signalR).

Comment: Hi @Aminos I am proficient in troubleshooting SignalR. I finally investigated your problem and found that the format of tokenResponse.AccessToken returned by the RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync method of SignalRIdentityServerClient is the RS256 algorithm.

Comment: Hi @Aminos In the way of generating tokens that I shared earlier, I modified the expiration time, such as 10 minutes, and then hard-coded it in options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult("ej...");, and everything ran fine.

Comment: @Aminos So I strongly recommend that you can create a new post and continue to follow up on this issue. In this post, my answer includes code and screenshots. It is difficult for other community members to join in. And we also found the cause of the problem, right?

Comment: I didn't understand your last comments. The goal of my question is to use IdentityServer to authenticate my client that must use a "client secret" stored in Identity Server and not using a random security key. My mistake was to include other projects in the solution I gave to you that had nothing to do with my question. I'd prefer you to edit your answer Jason.